# How to use SELECT DISTINCT ON with MySQL and Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have quite a complex query to essentially **select the cheapest delivery service price per delivery service**.

In order to get unique records per delivery service, I utilise the `DISTINCT` function in SQL. This query provides correct results:

```
DeliveryServicePrice.active.select('DISTINCT ON (delivery_service_id) *').order('delivery_service_id, price ASC')
```

(only a part of the query)

However, this query only seems to work with PostgreSQL (which I think is strange considering PostgreSQL is a lot more strict with SQL standards); it does not work with MySQL and SQLite. I receive the following error:

> Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'ON (delivery_service_id) * FROM `delivery_service_prices` 
>   WHERE `delivery_servi' at line 1: SELECT DISTINCT ON
>   (delivery_service_id) * FROM `delivery_service_prices`  WHERE
>   `delivery_service_prices`.`active` = 1 AND (2808.0 >= min_weight AND
>   2808.0 <= max_weight AND 104.0 >= min_length AND 104.0 <= max_length AND 104.0 >= min_thickness AND 104.0 <= max_thickness)  ORDER BY delivery_service_id, price ASC

The application I'm building is open source, so it's required to support all 3 database types. 
How do I create `DISTINCT ON` queries for MySQL and SQLite in the Rails framework syntax?

I'm using Rails 4.1.

#### Resources

My previous problem for reference:
[How to select unique records based on foreign key column in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26448520/how-to-select-unique-records-based-on-foreign-key-column-in-rails)

[File and line number for where the query is being used.](https://github.com/Jellyfishboy/trado/blob/master/app/models/cart.rb#L58)

### Finished answer

```
DeliveryServicePrice.select('delivery_service_prices.id').active.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN delivery_service_prices t2 ON (delivery_service_prices.delivery_service_id = t2.delivery_service_id AND delivery_service_prices.price > t2.price)').where('t2.delivery_service_id IS NULL')
```

Comment: DISTINCT * FROM delivery_service_id?

Comment: Did you try: `DeliveryServicePrice.active.distinct(:delivery_service_id).order('delivery_service_id, price ASC')`?

Comment: This query doesn't return the correct results, it just returns all the records since there is no DISTINCT condition. Translates to: `SELECT DISTINCT 'delivery_service_prices'.* FROM 'delivery_service_prices' WHERE 'delivery_service_prices'.'active' = 1  ORDER BY delivery_service_id, price ASC`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**`DISTINCT ON`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) is a Postgres specific extension to the standard SQL **`DISTINCT`**. Neither of them is a "function", both are SQL key words - even though the parentheses required after `DISTINCT ON` make it *look* like a function.

There are a couple of techniques to rewrite this with standard-SQL, all of them more verbose, though. Since MySQL does not support window-functions `row_number()` is out.

Details and more possible query techniques:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)
- [Fetch the row which has the Max value for a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column/123481)

Rewritten with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   delivery_service_prices d1
WHERE  active = 1
AND    2808.0 BETWEEN min_weight AND max_weight
AND    104.0  BETWEEN min_length AND max_length
AND    104.0  BETWEEN min_thickness AND max_thickness
AND NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   delivery_service_prices d2
   WHERE  active = 1
   AND    2808.0 BETWEEN min_weight AND max_weight
   AND    104.0  BETWEEN min_length AND max_length
   AND    104.0  BETWEEN min_thickness AND max_thickness
   AND    d2.delivery_service_id = d1.delivery_service_id
   AND    d2.price < d1.price 
   AND    d2.<some_unique_id> < d1.<some_unique_id>  -- tiebreaker!
   )
ORDER  BY delivery_service_id
```

- If there can be multiple rows with the same price for the same `delivery_service_id`, you need to add some unique tie-breaker to avoid multiple results per `delivery_service_id`. At least if you want a perfectly equivalent query. My example would select the row with the smallest `<some_unique_id>` from each set of dupes.
- Unlike with `DISTINCT ON`, `ORDER BY` is optional here.

Comment: Thanks for your response, your query worked and it discovered a flaw in my delivery service price logic (unique prices per delivery service). I ended up using the following query as it performed quicker: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column/123481#123481.

It also enabled me to merge the second query, so now I can execute all the arguments in one query.

Comment: @JellyFishBoy: Nice harvest. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
DeliveryServicePrice.active.select(:delivery_service_id).distinct.order('delivery_service_id, price ASC')
```

Comment: This query doesn't return the correct data, I'm looking to select delivery service price records, not their delivery_service_id attribute.