# how to use DISTINCT ON with mysql using ActiveRecord

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Want all the latest visit of all the distinct user.

For this I am using below query

```
Event.order(time: :desc).select('DISTINCT ON(user_id) user_id, time')
```

Getting SQL syntax error.

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON(user_id) user_id, time FROM `events` ORDER BY `events`.`time` DESC ' at line 1: SELECT  DISTINCT ON(user_id) user_id, time FROM `events` ORDER BY `events`.`time` DESC LIMIT 11)
```

events table column names

```
["id", "visit_id", "user_id", "name", "properties", "time"]
```

can anyone help me out in this

**Expected output something like this**

```
{ 21 => "2018-12-18 09:44:59", 42 => "2018-12-19 12:08:59"}
```

21 is user_id and value is last visit time

**Using mysql as database**

Comment: `ON(user_id)` is not valid MySQL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use SELECT DISTINCT ON with MySQL and Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26894868/how-to-use-select-distinct-on-with-mysql-and-rails)

Comment: `DISTINCT ON(columns). *` is PostgreSQL syntax but you can workaround it in MySQL with [SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(..))](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ioddCbTbeHgTKcCeHHzLpL/1) syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want all user visits with last visited time.

Instead of use `DISTINCT` function, you can use `GROUP` with `MAX` function.

Query looks like

```
Events.group(:user_id).maximum(:time)
```

This Outputs your desired results

```
{21=>Tue, 18 Dec 2018 11:15:24 UTC +00:00, 23=>Thu, 20 Dec 2018 06:42:10 UTC +00:00}
```

Hope this works for you.

FYI
DISTINCT ON(columns). is PostgreSQL Syntax.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't return ActiveRecord objects...

Answer (score 1):

Like i said in the comments `DISTINCT ON(column), *` is PostgreSQL SQL syntax.

The query below you need to have to rewrite in MySQL

```
SELECT 
 DISTINCT ON(user_id) AS user_id, time
FROM 
 <table>
ORDER BY 
 time DESC
LIMIT 11
```

The most easy to do that is using `SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(..))`. 
The queries below should give you the correct results.

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = @@max_allowed_packet;

SELECT 
   user_id
 , SUBSTRING_INDEX(
     GROUP_CONCAT(time
                  ORDER BY
                     time DESC
     )
     , ','
     , 1
 ) AS time
FROM 
 <table>
GROUP BY 
 user_id
ORDER BY 
 time DESC
LIMIT 11
```