# MySQL UNION show duplicates in DataTables

Tags: mysql, datatables, duplicates, row, union

This is driving me crazy.
I have two tables which contain invoice data.
I have a customer who has one unpaid invoice in each table.
I'm using this code to join the data from the two tables and get the two invoice rows:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare ("

    SELECT invoice_id, invoice_number, customer_id, paid 
    FROM 
    ( 
      SELECT invoice_id, invoice_number, customer_id, paid FROM tbl_invoices
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT invoice_id, invoice_number, customer_id, paid FROM tbl_invoices_el
    ) 
    tbl_invoices
    WHERE customer_id = $customer_id 
    AND paid = '0'
    GROUP BY invoice_number
");
```

The code works fine in phpMyAdmin, the result is two rows with the data.
On the page I'm using Bootstrap + DataTables to show the result in a modal window. The strange: no matter how I try, the first invoice is repeated two times. As I said before the code works fine in phpMyAdmin, the `var_dump()` of the fetched result is showing two arrays, as expected. What I'm doing wrong here?

**UPDATE** The `$output .=""`wasn't empty. My fault. @Barmar discovered the issue.

```
$stmt->execute();
$all_result = $stmt->fetchAll();
$total_rows = $stmt->rowCount();
if ( $total_rows > 0 )  
{
   foreach ($all_result as $row )  
     { 
     /* $output .=" ........... removed */
      echo " 
      <tr style='font-size:13px;'>
        <td width='5%'>
            <div class='form-check' style='margin-bottom:0px'>
                <label class='form-check-label'>
                  <input data-attr='" .$row['invoice_number']. "' id='" .$row['invoice_id']. "' class='form-check-input' type='checkbox' value='" .$customer_id. "'> 
                  <span class='form-check-sign'>
                    <span class='check'></span>
                  </span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td width='15%'>".$row['invoice_number']."</td>
      </tr>   
    ";
    /* echo $output; ........... removed */
  }
}
```

The result of var_dump():
[image: The result of var_dump()]

Comment: GROUP BY without aggregation is almost always a mistake, what are you expecting GROUP BY to do? Also, since that use of GROUP BY guarantees you would not have duplicate invoice_number values, I can only conclude/guess the problem is in the php loop you are have omitted from the code.

Comment: If only MySQL would implement `DISTINCT ON (invoice_number), invoice_id customer_id, paid` (PostgreSQL syntax) to unduplicate in MySQL/MariaDB you can emulate/simulate [that PostgreSQL syntax (post off me)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53868870/how-to-use-distinct-on-with-mysql-using-activerecord/53869691#53869691)..

Comment: But for better help i advice you to post example data as text formatted data (no images) and expected result so you get better help. See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Uuerdo - You're right removing  `GROUP BY invoice_number` doesn't change the output I updated my code with the loop. Just before the data goes in the DataTables the output is correct.

Comment: @Uueerdo - Good idea to suggest me about the omitted php loop, somehow the solution comes from your comment. Unfortunally I can't upvote a comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way you can get duplicate invoice numbers when you have `GROUP BY invoice_number`, so the code you showed can't produce that duplicate.

I suspect the problem is that you didn't clear `$output`, and there's some previous output with the first invoice number. Put:

```
$output = "";
```

before the `foreach` loop.