# How to clean the duplicate using this code?

Tags: mysql

I need to get the fastest players who reach certain milestone with minimum total games in the following simplified table:

```
create table eg(
kills integer, 
matchid integer,
playername varchar(30)
date date
)

INSERT INTO eg (kills,matchid,playername,date) values(12,1,'niko','2015-01-01');
INSERT INTO eg (kills,matchid,playername,date) values(13,2,'niko','2015-01-02');
INSERT INTO eg (kills,matchid,playername,date) values(5,3,'device','2015-01-03');
INSERT INTO eg (kills,matchid,playername,date) values(6,4,'niko','2015-01-04');
INSERT INTO eg (kills,matchid,playername,date) values(5,5,'device','2015-01-05');
INSERT INTO eg (kills,matchid,playername,date) values(5,3,'device','2015-01-06');
INSERT INTO eg (kills,matchid,playername,date) values(5,3,'device','2015-01-07');
```

but it caused duplicate.

The query i used is as followed:

```
select distinct(playername),sum_value,game_played
from(
select playername,
sum(kills) over (partition by playername order by date asc, matchid asc) as sum_value,
count(*) over (partition by playername order by date asc, matchid asc) as game_played
from eg) as so
where sum_value>15
order by game_played asc
```

the result I ideally want is the below

```
playname  sum_value game_played
niko          25          2
device        20          4
```

but what i got is:

```
playname  sum_value game_played
niko          25          2
niko          31          3
device        20          4
```

So I would prefer a modification to the query that removes dublicate names and only give me the first instance of the player name.

can someone help me with this? Thanks

Comment: The parentheses suggest that you think `distinct` applies to a particular column. It applies to the entire `SELECT` list.

Comment: Why should it return `niko 25 2` and not `niko 31 3` in the desired result?

Comment: The window function means you want a running total, why should it only return one row for each player?

Comment: oh i mean i need to get the player who is the fastest to reach the milestone. so niko 25 2 but not niko 31 3

Comment: *"The parentheses suggest that you think distinct applies to a particular column. It applies to the entire SELECT list"* @Barmar sometimes i wished `DISTINCT ON(column), *` (PostgreSQL syntax) is standard SQL and also supported by MySQL, i wrote a [emulation/simulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53868870/how-to-use-distinct-on-with-mysql-using-activerecord/53869691#53869691) once for MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a window function on the result of the subquery to get the first row for each player.

```
select playername,sum_value,game_played
from (
    SELECT *, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY playername ORDER BY game_played) `rank`
    from(
        select playername,
            sum(kills) over (partition by playername order by date asc, matchid asc) as sum_value,
            count(*) over (partition by playername order by date asc, matchid asc) as game_played
        from eg) as so
    where sum_value>15) AS t1
WHERE `rank` = 1
order by game_played asc
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/r9Seck5f6xzFpe1i5BjDak/0)